# Please check if pipelines with the same name were previously submitted to a different endpoint

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-training, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm getting below error whenever I tried to run a pipeline job using vertex-ai managed Jupiter notebook.

here I make sure that I'm creating a unique pipeline name every time by appending a timestamp in pipeline name sting. e.g my display name will be like `AutoML-Pipeline-DS-v4-1637251623` still I'm getting errors like  `Please check if pipelines with the same name were previously submitted to a different endpoint.`

here I'm using `google-cloud-aiplatform==1.4.3` to run the pipeline job. also, I'm following this [example](https://github.com/googleapis/python-aiplatform#pipelines) from GCP.

```
com.google.cloud.ai.platform.common.errors.AiPlatformException: code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, message=User-specified resource ID must match the regular expression '[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,127}', cause=null; Failed to update context (id = projects/xxxx/locations/us-central1/metadataStores/default/contexts/AutoML-Pipeline-DS-v4-1637251623). Please check if pipelines with the same name were previously submitted to a different endpoint. If so, one may submit the current pipeline with a different name to avoid reusing the existing MLMD Context from the other endpoint.; Failed to update pipeline and run contexts: project_number=xxxx, job_id=xxxx.; Failed to handle the job: {project_number = xxxx, job_id = xxxx}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please check regex, The word should be like this `automlipelinedsv41637251623`

Comment: yes above fixed work for me.